# Print the same output as shown in the Python REPL

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following Python shell dump:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime(2014,1,1)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> print(d)
2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

How can I create the string `'datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)'` within a Python 3 program?

My objective is to generate code from a snapshot of data in order to provide a fixed set of data for unit testing.  I tried searching "python print repl output" and similar terms, and didn't find the answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the list of [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and [repr(*object*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) caught my eye.

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`, otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object. A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a `__repr__()` method.

Sample code, extending from the question's terminal:

```
>>> repr(d)
'datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)'
>>> print(repr(d))
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```